# Dynamic UITableViewTable and IBOutlets

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

It is not allowed to have repeated content in UITableViews. We cannot connect a UILabel for example in the TableViewController as an IBOutlet. We can of course subclass the TableViewCell and set some values when the cellforRow... is called.

But how can we handle situation when an event needs to be handled? For example I have a UIDatePicker that sends the new date via an IBAction.

```
- (IBAction)dateChanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender {

    //how can I set the value of the sender in a UILabel?

}
```

The dataChanged is triggered everytime the user modifies the UI element, however I don't know how to pass the value to my UILabel since I don't have an IBOutlet for that label. In static cells I have an IBOutlet (myTxtLabel) and when the
date is changed I save the value with

> self.myTxtLabel = sender.value

How do we handle this case in dynamic UITableViews?

Comment: you can even have an outlet in dynamic tableviews too. What do you mean by dynamic tableview? I assume your number of rows will change at somepoint.IS that what you mean by dynamic?

Comment: There are no static cells. How can I have outlets in non static views.

Comment: Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.

Comment: By subclassing UITableViewCell, creating cell prototype and it will be used by dynamic content. Its almost the same as static, just different data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my take on this:

**Step 1 :** Create a custom cell by subclassing `UITableViewCell`.

**Step 2 :** Set the `tag` property on your `UIDatePicker` to the value of row number.

**Step 3 :** Fetch the row number from `tag` property in your `dateChanged:` method call.

**Step 4 :** Use the row number to get the cell and update the label on it:

```
- (IBAction)dateChanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender {
    NSInteger rowNumber = sender.tag;
    NSIndexPath *pickerRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowNumber inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:pickerRow];
    cell.myLabel.text = @"the updated text";
}
```

Comment: I would really suggest moving on from using tags, had problems with it too many times.

Comment: I have been using tags in multiple projects with no issues. This property is meant for solving certain issues like this.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you want change the date and then have that changed date get reflected across all the UITableView cells that have the date in them, but the problem is since that's repeated content, it can't have an outlet.

So, here's what I'd do. Keep a property for the date, when the user changes the date, in your method that gets called after changing the date, call either `self.tableView reloadData` or `self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPath:withAnimation:` to update just those rows. Then, in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` set the date up as normal using that property, so when you call reloadData, it is automatically updated.

Comment: Thanks for answering. This  answer is correct, however I would like to avoid reloadData.